# How to use Video room type "go" in React Native?

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-video

I am using 'react-native-twilio-video-webrtc' for the Twilio Video integration. I wanted to create a video room of type 'go', But unable to find the way.

I try,

```
import {
  TwilioVideoLocalView,
  TwilioVideoParticipantView,
  TwilioVideo,
} from 'react-native-twilio-video-webrtc';

...


twilioVideo.current?.connect(
      {
        token: iprops.token,
        roomName: iprops.roomName,
        type: 'go',
      }
    );
```

But seems like It's simply creating the room of type 'group' only.